# Safari share extension - App only appears in share menu after second attempt onwards since iOS 14

Tags: ios, ios14, ios-app-extension, ios8-share-extension

Our app relies on the use of Safari share extension. Like many others have reported before me, since upgrading to iOS 14 the app no longer appears in the share menu on first attempt. Only on second attempt onwards does it appear in the share extension. It was not an issue before iOS14.

We're noticing that some apps always appear on first share, eg AirDrop, Messages, Mail, WhatsApp, Messenger, Facebook, Gmail, Slack, Pinterest. While others (including ours) only show up after second attempt onwards, eg Zoom, Skype, LinkedIn, Notes, Reminders.

We have heard rumours that it might be possible to overcome due to some weirdness, such as a combination of content types supported: like Text, WebURL and WebPage during page load (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AppExtensionKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014212-SW2).

So far we have been experimenting with the NSExtensionActivationRules trying to find any combination of extension keys that will cause the app to appear in the share sheet on first attempt, but without luck.

Does anyone have any ideas what else might be worth trying? Any input is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!